# Fail the process if any failure while producing record on Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to fail the process whenever the KafkaProducer fails while producing record on kafka topic due to any reason.

I am sending records like below:

```
for(String message : messages) {
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, message), (metadata, ex) -> {
        if (ex != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

I am re throwing the exception in call. So my expectation was that the process will fail, apparently the for loop continues to execute.

How to fail the sending process as soon as we get any exception in Callback?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if the send command succeeds the variable "ex" will be null so, having a look on the code you included, the RuntimeException is not going to be thrown as long as the message is successfully sent.

If you want to force an error to check which is the behavior I recommend you to stop all your brokers and then try to send a message. After a while, when the timeout happens you will be able to see the exception in your Callback.

To summarize:

```
    Successful send: (metadata != null, ex == null)
    Failed send:     (metadata == null, ex != null)
```

P.S. Remember to close the producer when the exception is thrown:

```
    for(String message : messages) {
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, message), (metadata, ex) -> {
            if (ex != null) {
                producer.close();
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception Happened: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I want to break for loop as soon as I get an exception, and I want to propagate that exception to main thread for logging purpose. how to do that?

Comment: I am not really sure about your exact purposes but the for loop will stop after the throw command. About the logging and having a look on the close() documentation:

"If close() is called from Callback, a warning message will be logged and close(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) will be called instead."